# What regex engine does GitLab use?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Let's say I have a rule like this,

```
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /^(fix|feat|perf|docs|build|test|ci|refactor)\S*:/'
```

It occurs to me that `^` does not match the start of any line in a multiline regex, only the start of the first line. That raises the question,

- Does anything match the newline?
- Is there a multi-line regex mode?

Where is the GitLab Regex documented? What Regex implementation do they use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer, according to [these docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#only--except-regex-syntax):

> In GitLab 11.9.4, GitLab began internally converting the regexp used in only and except keywords to RE2.
>
> RE2 limits the set of available features due to computational complexity, and some features, like negative lookaheads, became unavailable. Only a subset of features provided by Ruby Regexp are now supported.
>
> From GitLab 11.9.7 to GitLab 14.9, GitLab provided a feature flag to let you use unsafe regexp syntax. We’ve fully migrated to RE2 now, and that feature flag is no longer available.

The same is true for `rules` and `if`, like you are using.

TL;DR: GitLab regexps now use Google's [RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), not Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab uses [Ruby's core regex implementation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html) which is [Onigmo (Oniguruma-mod)](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo). I found that from looking at the source code in Ruby's [`regex.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/regexec.c).

Official documentation is mostly here: https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE